# Trying to update a label that serves as a counter but no luck

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a side bar with a label that should get updated when I press a button. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li class="active" runat="server"><a href="#">
    <asp:Label ID="labelNavigate" Text=" Navigate" runat="server"/> 
    <asp:Label CssClass="badge" ID="CurrentQ" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>
  </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">
    <asp:Button ID="IncrementButton" BackColor="Transparent" OnClick="MasterButton_Click"  runat="server" Text="Next Question" BorderStyle="None"/>
  </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">
    <asp:Button ID="DecrementButton" BackColor="Transparent" OnClick="MasterButton_Click"  runat="server" Text="Previous Question" BorderStyle="None"/>
  </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">
    <asp:Button ID="Hint" BackColor="Transparent" OnClick="Hint_Click"  runat="server" Text="Help Me!" BorderStyle="None"/>
  </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I press the button with the ID=IncrementButton but the label with ID=CurrentQ never gets updated. I check in the code behind while debugging and it states that the CurrentQ.Text is the correct number I want but the results remain 0 which is the original number of question no matter how many times I press the button. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here I have look everywhere and cannot seem to break this one. Thank you in advance and I appreciate it.

This is the code behind:

```
protected void MasterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button bt = (Button)sender;
    if (QNo.Text == "")
        return;
    if (bt.ID == "IncrementButton")
    {
        if (this.Offset == (Convert.ToInt32(QNo.Text))-1)
            return;
    }
    else if (bt.ID == "DecrementButton")
    {
        if (this.Offset == 0)
            return;
    }
    switch (bt.ID)
    {
        case "IncrementButton":
            this.Offset = this.Offset + 1;
            break;
        case "DecrementButton":
            this.Offset = this.Offset - 1;
            break;
    }
    //event for the content page to use to update it's content
    CurrentQ.Text = (Offset + 1).ToString();
    ChangeQuestion(this,EventArgs.Empty);

}
```

Comment: Are there any other places where `CurrentQ.Text` is assigned a value? Have you checked if those are being called after the button click event?

Comment: I went through the whole project and made sure there was no other place where CurrentQ.Text was being assigned. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the value of `Offset` does not persist, every time you click the button the counter is reset to its original value.

Define `Offset` in the page's ViewState.

```
public int Offset
{
    get
    {
        return (int)(ViewState["Offset"] ?? 0);
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Offset"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kennyzx I do have it defined in the ViewState and not doing it.

Comment: set a break point to the line `CurrentQ.Text = (Offset + 1).ToString();`, will it be hit?

Comment: Yes it is hit and in the code behind the value of CurrentQ.Text is set to the appropriate number.

Comment: but the label text is not updated to "Navigate 2" after the first click? i don't know but it is working fine in my test.

Comment: correct...I have been breaking my head with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have figured out the problem. I had declared the Buttons that would increment the badge as

```
RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(DecrementButton);
```

this is so I can generate a question in an updatepanel on the main content page therefore I had to create and update panel surround my label and then put a  for AsyncPostBack as well that would respond to the on click of both the DecrementButton and the IncrementButton.

Thank you for those that took interest in my question I usually do not bother much but this one was giving me extra headache was about to give up on it which I don't generally do until I fix the problem.